# Enable Overlay Scrollbars In all Applications

Tags: 11.04, unity, overlay-scrollbars

Is there a way to *force* all applications to use the Natty overlay scrollbars?

Examples: Chrome doesn't use it, neither does Firefox, gnome-terminal or a host of other applications.

[image: Google Chrome scrollbars]

[image: gnome-terminal scrollbars]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are currently no way to do it. 
Currently only native Gtk applications support the overlay-scrollbars, additional support will eventually come later on.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. 

So `gnome-terminal` isn't a native GTK application?

Comment: It is, but it has a custom dark theme...

Comment: Gotcha. Just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: http://testcases.qa.ubuntu.com/Applications/System/Scrollbars - looks like you *can* enable them for everything.

Comment: Acording to that link, Gwibber it's supported. But Gwibber has overlay Scrollbars only on account selector (left edge) and don't on twitts. http://ubuntuone.com/p/r9L/