# Overlay scrollbar for Chromium browser

Tags: chromium, overlay-scrollbars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable Overlay Scrollbars In all Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35770/enable-overlay-scrollbars-in-all-applications)

Will Chromium Browser ever get overlay scrollbar? Like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused - did you edit that screenshot?

Comment: Yes. This image shows how Chromium browser should look like (with overlay scrollbar).

Comment: I already tried LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=foo chromium-browser but it doesn't working.